# xml to linq with two class c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, oop

I am trying to read an XML document with linq and store it into a list of item. I have a class named "Item", which contain another class named "Effet". I am able to create an item, but not to have "Effet" initialized. (Either is stays null, or I get a compiler error if I try to write it different)
I tried multiple things, nothing worked. Here is what I tried. (Currently commented)

Here is my code:
Function that read XML

```
//Charge les items du jeu dans une liste<Item>
public static List<Item> chargerItems(string cheminFichier)
{
    XElement xmlDoc = XElement.Load(cheminFichier);

    List<Item> listeItem = (
        from i in xmlDoc.Elements("item")
        select new Item()
        {
            Nom = (string)i.Element("nom").Value,
            Cout =  int.Parse(i.Element("cout").Value),
            Ville = int.Parse(i.Element("ville").Value),                   
           Effet =  (from eff in i.Element("effet").Elements("effet") select new Effet { Duree = eff.Value})
                //     {
               // Cible = null,
                //Categorie = (Categorie)Enum.Parse(typeof(Categorie), (string)i.Element("categorie"))//,
                // Magnitude =  (int)i.Element("magnitude"),
               // Duree = (int)i.Element("duree")
         //   } 
            //(

            //  from eff in i.Elements("effet")
            //  select new Effet

            //  {
            //      //Cible =  (Monstre) eff.Element("cible"),
            //      Categorie = (Categorie) Enum.Parse(typeof(Categorie), (string)eff.Element("categorie")),
            //      Magnitude = (int)eff.Element("magnitude"),
            //      Duree = (int)eff.Element("duree"),

            //  }
            //  ) as Effet  
        }


        ).ToList();

    return listeItem;
}
```

My two classes:

```
namespace RPGProject.Entity
{
    public class Effet
    {
        public Monstre Cible { get; set; }
        public Categorie Categorie { get; set; }
        public int Magnitude { get; set; }
        public int Duree { get; set; }

        public Effet()
        {
            //this.Cible = null;
            //this.Categorie = Categorie.Divers;
            this.Magnitude = 0;
            this.Duree = 0;
        }

    }
}

namespace RPGProject
{
    public enum Categorie
    {
        Guérison,
        Résurrection,
        Attaque,
        Stimulant, //Gain en force, énergie, etc
        Divers //Orbe, sphère de capture
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Nom { get; set; }
        public Effet Effet { get; set; }
        public int Cout { get; set; } //$$$
        public int Ville { get; set; }
        public int Rarete { get; set; }

        public Item() {}
        public Item(string nom) { this.Nom = nom; }

        public Item(string nom, Effet effet, int cout, int ville)
        {
            this.Nom = nom;
            this.Effet =  new Effet();
            this.Cout = cout;
            this.Ville = ville;
        }

        //Redéfinition afin de pouvoir comparer les items du dictionnaire 
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var k = obj as Item;
            if (k != null)
            {
                return this.Nom == k.Nom;
            }
            return base.Equals(obj);
        }

        //Redéfinition afin de pouvoir comparer les items du dictionnaire 
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.Nom.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

XML file

```
<liste_item>
    <item>
        <nom>Seringue d'adrénaline</nom>
        <effet>
            <cible></cible>
            <categorie>Résurrection</categorie>
            <magnitude>0</magnitude>
            <duree>1</duree>
        </effet>
        <categorie></categorie>
        <cout>250</cout>
        <ville>1</ville>
    </item>
</liste_item>
```

Comment: You should post a sample of the XML that you're trying to read from

Comment: You are right, I added it via the "Share edit link"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not that far off.  Try making your LINQ query like this:

```
List<Item> listeItem = (
   from i in xmlDoc.Elements("item")
   let eff = i.Element("effet")
   select new Item()
   {
       Nom = i.Element("nom").Value,
       Cout = int.Parse(i.Element("cout").Value),
       Ville = int.Parse(i.Element("ville").Value),
       Effet = new Effet
       {
           Categorie = (Categorie)Enum.Parse(typeof(Categorie), eff.Element("categorie").Value),
           Magnitude = int.Parse(eff.Element("magnitude").Value),
           Duree = int.Parse(eff.Element("duree").Value)
       }
   }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It usually helps to factor out the creation of sub-objects into a method, like this:

```
private Effet GetEffet(XElement x)
{
    var elEffet = x.Element("effet");
    return new Effet()
    {
        Duree = int.Parse(elEffet.Element("duree").Value),
        Magnitude = int.Parse(elEffet.Element("magnitude").Value)
    };
}
```

This gives you a better overview of the cod ein the Linq statement and also helps when debugging the code later on because you can set a breakpoint in the method.

You can read the XML like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("XmlFile1.xml");
var listeItem = (from x in doc.Root.Elements("item")
                 select new Item(x.Element("nom").Value,
                 GetEffet(x),
                 int.Parse(x.Element("cout").Value),
                 int.Parse(x.Element("ville").Value))).ToList();
```

I've also spotted a small error in the constructor of the Item class. Instead of assigning a new `Effet` object, I guess you meant to assign the value of the parameter:

```
public Item(string nom, Effet effet, int cout, int ville)
{
    this.Nom = nom;
    this.Effet = effet; // Change this line
    this.Cout = cout;
    this.Ville = ville;
}
```

Please note that I've left out some classes and properties in the sample code for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both of you. I like the idea of making a method to help with the debugging, I didn't know I could do that.

Both answer solve my problem.